# Using stringdata from serial port to manipulate galvo scanners goes wrong at higher speeds

Tags: python, c++, arduino, windows-10, pyserial

I´m using a galvo scanner to manipulate a laser. I get the data from the serial port. Also I´m sending the data back to the serial Monitor and there I don´t have any problems. So the problem should be transfering the data from the arduino to the display and galvo drivers. If I use timesleep=1 second on python side it works. But it needs to be faster.

I already tried to change some delays and adjusted the baudrate.

The Arduino Code I use:

```
///// Declaration for laser

#include "Laser.h"

// Create laser instance (with laser pointer connected to digital pin 5)
Laser laser(5);

///// Declaration for the OLED /////

#include "U8glib.h" // LCD Lib
//define ADDRESS 0x3C// address of display
U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 u8g(U8G_I2C_OPT_NONE|U8G_I2C_OPT_DEV_0);

///// Declatation of variables /////

const byte numChars = 32;
char receivedChars[numChars];
char tempChars[numChars];        // temporary array for use when parsing

// variables to hold the parsed data
char messageFromPC[numChars] = {0};
int integerFromPC = "";
int integerFromPC2 = 0;
int integerFromPC3 = 0;
//float floatFromPC = 0.0;

boolean newData = false;


//===============================================
///////////////////////////////
///////////// Setup ///////////
///////////////////////////////


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); //9600 Standard
  laser.init();
  //laser.resetClipArea();
  laser.setScale(1);
  //laser.setOffset(0,0);
  // assign default color value
  if ( u8g.getMode() == U8G_MODE_R3G3B2 ) {
    u8g.setColorIndex(255);     // white
  }
  else if ( u8g.getMode() == U8G_MODE_GRAY2BIT ) {
    u8g.setColorIndex(3);         // max intensity
  }
  else if ( u8g.getMode() == U8G_MODE_BW ) {
    u8g.setColorIndex(1);         // pixel on
  }
  else if ( u8g.getMode() == U8G_MODE_HICOLOR ) {
    u8g.setHiColorByRGB(255,255,255);
  }

  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
}


//===============================================
///////////////////////////////
///////////// Loop ////////////
///////////////////////////////

void loop() {

  ///// OLED: wait for serial /////
    u8g.firstPage();
    do {
    draw();
    }
    while( u8g.nextPage() );

    recvWithStartEndMarkers();
    if (newData == true) {
        strcpy(tempChars, receivedChars);
            // this temporary copy is necessary to protect the original data
            //   because strtok() used in parseData() replaces the commas with \0
        parseData();
        showParsedData();
        newData = false;
    }
    SerToLaser();

//   delay(10);
}



//========================================================

///////////////////////////////
////////// Functions //////////
///////////////////////////////

///// Info before receiving serial information /////

void draw(void) {
  u8g.setFont(u8g_font_unifont);
  //u8g.setFont(u8g_font_osb21);
  u8g.drawStr( 5, 10, "ser_data: NO");
  u8g.drawStr( 5, 25, "Laser: OFF");
  u8g.drawStr( 5, 45, "x: --");
  u8g.drawStr( 65, 45, "y: --");
}

///// Info when receiving serial information & print received values /////

void draw2(void) {
  // graphic commands to redraw the complete screen should be placed here
  u8g.setFont(u8g_font_unifont);
  //u8g.setFont(u8g_font_osb21);
  u8g.drawStr( 5, 10, "ser_data: YES");

  u8g.drawStr( 5, 25, "Laser:");
  u8g.setPrintPos(65, 25); // set position 25,35
  u8g.print(messageFromPC); // display laser status

  u8g.drawStr( 5, 45, "x:");
  u8g.setPrintPos(20, 45); // set position 25,35
  u8g.print(integerFromPC2); // display x-coordinate

  u8g.drawStr( 65, 45, "y: ");
  u8g.setPrintPos(80, 45); // set position 25,35
  u8g.print(integerFromPC3); // display y-coordinate


}


void SerToLaser(){

   switch (integerFromPC) {
   case 1:
       {
       // int serDataX = Serial.parseInt();
       // int serDataY = Serial.parseInt();            
       laser.sendtoRaw(integerFromPC2, integerFromPC3);
       laser.on();
       // picture loop
       u8g.firstPage();
       do {
         draw2();
       } while( u8g.nextPage() );
       integerFromPC = "";
       //delay(200);   ////////////////
       break;                                
       }
   case 0:
       {
       laser.off();
       // int serDataX = Serial.parseInt();
       // int serDataY = Serial.parseInt();             
       laser.sendtoRaw(integerFromPC2, integerFromPC3);
       // picture loop
       u8g.firstPage();
       do {
         draw2();
       } while( u8g.nextPage() );
       integerFromPC = "";
       //delay(200);   ////////////////
       break;                                
       }
   default:

       break;
       }



  }







void recvWithStartEndMarkers() {
    static boolean recvInProgress = false;
    static byte ndx = 0;
    char startMarker = '<';
    char endMarker = '>';
    char rc;

    while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
        rc = Serial.read();

        if (recvInProgress == true) {
            if (rc != endMarker) {
                receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
                ndx++;
                if (ndx >= numChars) {
                    ndx = numChars - 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
                recvInProgress = false;
                ndx = 0;
                newData = true;
            }
        }

        else if (rc == startMarker) {
            recvInProgress = true;
        }
    }
}

//============

void parseData() {      // split the data into its parts

    char * strtokIndx; // this is used by strtok() as an index

    strtokIndx = strtok(tempChars,",");      // get the first part - the string
    strcpy(messageFromPC, strtokIndx); // copy it to messageFromPC

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ","); // this continues where the previous call left off
    integerFromPC = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ","); // this continues where the previous call left off
    integerFromPC2 = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ","); // this continues where the previous call left off
    integerFromPC3 = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer

    //strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ",");
    //floatFromPC = atof(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to a float

}

//============

void showParsedData() {
    Serial.print("Laserstatus: ");
    Serial.println(messageFromPC);
    Serial.print("Statusnumber: ");
    Serial.println(integerFromPC);
    Serial.print("X: ");
    Serial.println(integerFromPC2);
    Serial.print("Y: ");
    Serial.println(integerFromPC3);

    SerToLaser();

}

//============
```

The Python Code I use:

```
import serial
import time
import random



ard = serial.Serial('com6',9600,timeout=5)
time.sleep(1.8) # wait for Arduino min 1.8

i = 0

while (i <4096):
    # Serial write section
    #int r = randint(0,100) 
    setX_Coor = i
    setY_Coor = 2000


    setStatus = 1#random.randint(0,1)
    #setX_Coor = random.randint(1000,4095) #63
    #setY_Coor = random.randint(1000,4095)#37
    ard.flush()
    setVal1 = str(setStatus)
    setVal2 = str(setX_Coor)
    setVal3 = str(setY_Coor)
    print ("Python value sent: ")
    print (setVal1.encode())
    print (setVal2.encode())
    print (setVal3.encode())


    ard.write(('<').encode())
    ard.write(('ON,').encode())
    ard.write((',').encode())
    ard.write(setVal1.encode())
    ard.write((',').encode())
    ard.write(setVal2.encode())
    ard.write((',').encode())
    ard.write(setVal3.encode())
    ard.write(('>').encode())



    time.sleep(1) # 0.08 is fastest possible value



    # Serial read section
    msg = ard.read(ard.inWaiting()) # read all characters in buffer
    print ("Message from arduino: ")
    print (msg)
    i = i + 10
else:
    print ("Exiting")
#exit()
```

The scanner should scan a line at y=2000 and change the value of x from 0-4095. It does the job for 3 seconds and then the y value is just 200 than 20 or 1 or some random numer...

Comment: What breaks when you take the sleep lower.  Could you add more description regarding the errors/ issues that you are running into?

Answer (score 0):

On first glance, it appears that you are doing a lot of redundant redraws (which is probably expensive *I have never used u8glib*).  You are doing a redraw once at the top of the main loop, then twice more due to your SerToLaser() twice (once at bottom of main loop, once inside showParsedData()).  Also (although 1 second is not fast at all), serial display is pretty expensive on the arduino, so you should be sparing on how much you print to the terminal.